# How to find the number of digits of an integer if the input is 0000? (The output must be 4 and not 1)

Tags: c

When calculating the number of digits, the compiler takes 0000 as a single 0 and the answer is 1. But the number of zeroes in each place must be calculated. For example : 0000 - 4
00 - 2

```
int n,c=0;
scanf("%d",&n);
do{
   n=n/10;
   c++;
}while(n!=0);
printf("%d",c);
```

Comment: Read it in as a string.

Comment: Scan the input as string and then you can check if it is a number and calculate the number of digits

Comment: To go a level deeper than the above comments - if you need to distinguish between `0000` and `0` then you are no longer talking about integers (as these are the same integer value).  To distinguish between representations, you need to retain the representation - easiest way is to store a string.

Comment: With input `"0102030"` what  is the result?  For input `"-0123"`?

Comment: storing as a string worked.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is in the comment above, but lets make this a full official answer :

If you talk about integers, 000 and 0 are the exact same.
So if you want to distinguish the two, you must treat the entry as a string instead, and completely forget there are numbers inside.
And for a string, it is easy to count how many characters there are.